# Can't return array elements from array of string using instance variables

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this model with an array of strings as one of the columns

```rb
  create_table "shows", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.time "st"
    t.time "ed"
    t.integer "money"
    t.string "av_seats", default: "--- []\n"
    t.string "oc_seats", default: "--- []\n"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "theatre_id"
    t.integer "screen_id"
    t.integer "movie_id"
    t.index ["movie_id"], name: "index_shows_on_movie_id"
    t.index ["screen_id"], name: "index_shows_on_screen_id"
    t.index ["theatre_id"], name: "index_shows_on_theatre_id"
  end
```

I'm trying to reference `av_seats` and `oc_seats` in another model's controller via this logic

```rb
def create
    @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
    @av_seats = Show.find(params[:show_id]).pluck(:av_seats)
    @oc_seats = Show.find(params[:show_id]).pluck(:oc_seats)

    if @booking.save
      if @av_seats.include? @booking.seat
        @oc_seats << @booking.seat
        @av_seats.delete @booking.seat
      end
      render json: @booking, status: :created, location: @booking
```

Essentially, it's supposed to move an element from one array to another and delete the same element from the previous array all based on input.

```
"status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "exception": "#<ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Show without an ID>",
```

I've tried using the `pluck` method beforehand and then attempt to use `find` for the element but I may not be doing it right either.

```rb
    @av = Show.pluck(:show_id, :av_seats)
    @oc = Show.pluck(:show_id, :oc_seats)

    @av_seats = Show.find(@av)
    @oc_seats = Show.find(@oc)
```

```rb
# routes.rb

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :movies
  resources :bookings
  resources :shows
  resources :screens
  resources :theatres
  resources :users
end
```

This is what the form typically looks like. It's an API so no views, just pure JSON.

```json
{
    "booking": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "show_id": 2,
        "screen_id": 2,
        "seat": "A5"
    }
}
```

Comment: = Show.find(params[:id])

Comment: If you're getting `Couldn't find Show without an ID` is because nothing comes in `params[:show_id]`.

Comment: can you show the contents of `params`, contents of routes.rb and the form that leads to the `create` action please.

Comment: What do you contents of params? Like the ids? @Pascal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a `Booking` resource.
The information (:show_id) is nested under the `:bookings` key in your params

I assume you got the following method on the `BookingsController`

```
def booking_params
  params.require(:booking).permit(:show_id, :user_id, :seat, :screen_id)
end
```

?

If your `Booking` has the association setup properly

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :show
end
```

Then you can access the show like this:

```
booking = Booking.new(booking_params)
show = booking.show
```

If no association is setup, then you can use

```
show = Show.find(params[:booking][:show_id])
# or
show = Show.find(booking_params[:show_id]) # not _params_
```

Since the show object is loaded anyhow, you can just access `av_seats` and `oc_seats` directly

```
show.av_seats
show.oc_seats
```

`pluck` is an optimization where only the columns you *pluck* are fetched from the DB.

You probably want to change the `xx_seats` columns to be of type `string[]` (with `array: true` in your migration).

Once you change the contents of the seats array(s) you need to save the show record.

Comment: Oh nice, yeah, I see what you mean. I managed to get it to finally resolve the error and it copies the characters just fine. But it doesn't delete it from `oc_seats` for some reason. Also, they already are strings, sqlite3 is just weird with how it does array of strings and it took some finnicking around.

Comment: Ah, sqlite does not support array types. So You might need to serialize and deserialize your array on your own. I don't use sqlite so not sure what the common way is though.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that, I figured that out before having this issue haha. In any case, I appreciate the help. I've managed to solve the error. It wasn't saving `show` afterwards so the effects wouldn't take place so I added a `show.save` to the logic.